# Insert output into another newly created table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How can I insert the output of below table into newly created `[DBname].[dbo].[Tablename]`?

The below T-SQL query outputs two columns: `server` and `name`.

#### T-SQL 1

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
drop table tempdb..#temp1

create table #temp1 
([server] nvarchar(200),
[name] nvarchar(200),
)

insert into  #temp1

SELECT  (select @@SERVERNAME) as Server,name FROM      master.sys.databases
select * from #temp1
```

I want to insert the output of **T-SQL 1** into a newly created table `[DBname].[dbo].[Tablename]`.I already created two columns `server` and `name`.

So far I tried like below:

```
Insert into [DBname].[dbo].[Tablename]

select 

if object_id ('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
drop table tempdb..#temp1

create table #temp1 
([server] nvarchar(200),
[name] nvarchar(200),
)

insert into  #temp1

SELECT  (select @@SERVERNAME) as Server,name FROM      master.sys.databases
select * from #temp1
```

I used the Stack Overflow Q & A referenced below, but somehow could not do what I need:

[How to do INSERT into a table records extracted from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `OUTPUT` clause.

Let's say you need to insert `#TEMP1` data into `#TAB2` when an `INSERT` is done on `#TEMP1`:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1 
([SERVER] NVARCHAR(200),
[NAME] NVARCHAR(200),
);

CREATE TABLE #TAB2 ([SERVER] NVARCHAR(200),
[NAME] NVARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO  #TEMP1
OUTPUT INSERTED.[SERVER],INSERTED.NAME INTO #TAB2
SELECT  (SELECT @@SERVERNAME) AS SERVER,NAME FROM MASTER.SYS.DATABASES;
```

Now see the results in both tables:

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP1;
SELECT * FROM #TAB2;
```

See the product documentation: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) for more information, including some important restrictions.

If you want to automate this process, you need to write an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. Please find a very good example exactly matching your requirement in [SQL Server: Coding the After Insert Trigger in SQL Server](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/41414/sql-server-coding-the-after-insert-trigger-in-sql-server/) by Vishwanath Dalvi.